# How can i fix the error for imports of own package?

Tags: python, python-import, python-importlib

I learn ML from the book [Introduction to Machine Learning with Python](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920030515.do).

When I try to import and run [mglearn](https://github.com/amueller/introduction_to_ml_with_python) package I have the error:

```
In:    import mglearn

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-26a0454c3f6e> in <module>
----> 1 import mglearn

~\Desktop\Introduction to Machine Learning with Python\ml_project\mglearn\__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from .import plots
      2 from .import tools
      3 from .plots import cm3, cm2
      4 from .tools import discrete_scatter
      5 from .plot_helpers import ReBl

~\Desktop\Introduction to Machine Learning with Python\ml_project\mglearn\plots.py in <module>
      1 from .plot_linear_svc_regularization import plot_linear_svc_regularization
----> 2 from .plot_interactive_tree import plot_tree_progressive, plot_tree_partition
      3 from .plot_animal_tree import plot_animal_tree
      4 from .plot_rbf_svm_parameters import plot_svm
      5 from .plot_knn_regression import plot_knn_regression

~\Desktop\Introduction to Machine Learning with Python\ml_project\mglearn\plot_interactive_tree.py in <module>
      6 from sklearn.externals.six import StringIO  # doctest: +SKIP
      7 from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
----> 8 from scipy.misc import imread
      9 from scipy import ndimage
     10 from sklearn.datasets import make_moons

ImportError: cannot import name 'imread' from 'scipy.misc'   (c:\users\boni\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\scipy\misc\__init__.py)
```

What I need to do for solve the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have `scipy` and `pillow` installed correctly?

Comment: @BenjaminStriner I have the `scipy` and the package works ! `pillow` not installed

Comment: Look at the post mentioned above.  @BenjaminStriner is onto something.  seems you need the **pillow** package installed

Comment: @Steve: Thanks! I install the pillow package, it isn't throw the error. I need to do some test... I think what it works :)